# eclipse first loading error

Tags: android, eclipse

I started a new project in eclipse android but there was a 3 errors in the beginning. I made a new project again but I had them again. There wasn't these errors before can anyone help ? these are first default codes main activity:

```
package com.persiansmarthome;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

These are the errors:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a
>   field MainActivity.java   /PersianSmartHome/src/com/persiansmarthome  line
>   15    Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type main cannot be resolved or is
>   not a
>   field MainActivity.java   /PersianSmartHome/src/com/persiansmarthome  line
>   22    Java Problem
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Don't include android.R here;
>   use a fully qualified name for each usage
>   instead   MainActivity.java   /PersianSmartHome/src/com/persiansmarthome  line
>   5 Android Lint Problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase the minimum sdk version in manifest.xm

Sounds like incorrect sdk / api version.
Check also your sdk version in your project properties and make sure you installed the relevant sdks in sdk manager

Comment: i changed min and target sdk many diffrent values but errors are not gone. what else problem can be? it wasnt before.

Comment: What is your min/target sdk? which api's are installed on your computer?

Comment: the last one. i think its 17 and minimumm of my project is android 2.2

Comment: Try to change to 10, make sure 10 is installed in your sdk manager

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
import android.R;
```

from your MainActivity.java file

For more details, look at [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error).

Comment: if i remove that line other problem happens

Comment: @user2921883 I have edited my answer to provide more details on the android.R issue. Your app should be using the R.java that's generated for you (located under gen folder at your project root) and not the android's resource file (android.R)